# tf.exe TF30063 unauthorized (VS 2022)

Tags: azure-devops

I had to change my corporate password which we also use for Azure access. I rebooted and logged in into the account again. I can access Azure TFS from Visual Studio without a problem. However, `tf.exe get .` does not work anymore because apparantly I am unauthorized. I checked the internet/[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609089/tf-exe-complains-that-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access) but the `credential manager` didn’t seem to hold any credentials I could clear and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\` does not contain a `Team Foundation` folder where I could delete any cache.

[image: Visual Studio works]

When I try to use a personal access token (PAT), then instead of two "denied"s, I only get one:

[image: Command line does not]